# How to convert written file's string elements to integer in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a file and written some random numbers by using file.write() . As i have to write these numbers into string format ex. file.write(str(scerets.randbelow(100)) + "\n"), now I want to read this file again and to save those string numbers into an integer list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your write your numbers with

```
file.write(str(scerets.randbelow(100)) + "\n")
```

And there's nothing else in that file, this should work to read it back:

```
numbers = [int(line) for line in file]
```

This assumes you've already opened the file in a "read mode" with something like this:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as file:
    numbers = [int(line) for line in file]
```

Comment: Ofer Sadan , suppose i have witten 100 values in the file. Then how can I convert them all in an integer list. ex. for i in range (100000):
    file.write(str(secrets.randbelow(100000))+"\n")
    
file.close()

Comment: @NoorMuhammadLight this code in my answer will give you back the whole list in `numbers`